# ImageButton onclick issue

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have used a selector file for `ImageButton` but the image which I have defined `onPress` is shown for only a very short period of time. I want that it will be visible until the next window opens.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/bedpres_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/bedpres_pressed" /> <!-- focused -->      
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/bedpres" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) in that case with the selector you have.

Answer (score 0):

Button is considered pressed only between the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` touch event actions, so if you want your button to change picture after it's been touched, you should make it manually, calling `button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bedpres_pressed);` Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After Button Cliked i think you wrote in xml file for only click
so if you want your button to change picture after it's been touched, you try to change  manually, calling button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bedpres_pressed);

other wise try to use Toggle Button class

hope this helps.